# Plotting Shapefile R - Incorrectly plots

Tags: r, dictionary, shapefile

I am trying to produce a map (picture attached) but wish to overlay my shapefile onto the map. I cannot get it to work at present - the code for the shapefile is at the very end and I have included the summary of the shapefile in case this is useful - I am unsure whether it is the format of the coordinate system or something simpler? I've also attached a link to the datafiles to make this reproducible (https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=9E74848E574367C6!2648&authkey=!AGApYipxXqSwZw4&ithint=folder%2ccsv)

```
 lon.data <- c(28.5, 29.5, 30.5, 31.5, 32.5, 33.5, 34.5, 35.5, 36.5)       # Define the longitudinal data for matrix creation
 lat.data <- c(-4.5, -3.5, -2.5, -1.5, -0.5,  0.5,  1.5,  2.5,  3.5,  4.5) # Define the latitudinal data for matrix creation
 nlons <- length(lon.data)
 nlats <- length(lat.data)

 x.limit <- range(lon.data, na.rm=T)
 y.limit <- range(lat.data, na.rm=T)

 Avg.Matrix.1 <- matrix(NB.GRACE[,123], nrow=nlons, ncol=nlats, byrow=F) # Form a matrix for 2003-2012 gridded averages

 Avg.Matrix.1[Avg.Matrix.1 > 30] <- 30   # Reports all TWS anomalies > 30 and 30cm
 Avg.Matrix.1[Avg.Matrix.1 < -30] <- -30 # Reports all TWS anomalies < -30 and -30cm
 tws.range <- c(-5,5)

 par(mar=c(7.8,6.3,0.4,6.3), mgp=c(1.5,0.5,0))

 image(lon.data, lat.data, Avg.Matrix.1, xlim=x.limit, ylim=y.limit, zlim=tws.range, asp=1, axes=F, 
  cex.axis=0.85, col=rev(tim.colors(60)), xlab="Longitude", ylab="Latitude", cex.lab=0.8)
 axis(1, at=seq(29, 36, by=1), labels=c("29°","30°","31°","32°","33°","34°","35°","36°"), cex.axis=0.8)
 axis(2, at=seq(-4, 4, by=1), labels=c("-4°","-3°","-2°","-1°","0°","1°","2°","3°","4°"), cex.axis=0.8, las=1)

 image.plot(zlim=tws.range, col=rev(tim.colors(50)), axis.args=c(cex.axis=0.9), legend.only=T)  
 grid(lwd=0.75, col="gray60", lty=1)
 abline(h=c(-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4), v=c(29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36), col="gray60", lty=3, lwd=0.5)
 box(lwd=1.5)
 LVB.Waterbodies <- readShapeLines("Victoria Water Areas.shp")
 map(LVB.Waterbodies, add=TRUE, col=1)


 LVB.Waterbodies
 class       : SpatialLinesDataFrame 
 features    : 1 
 extent      : 133171.2, 761398.7, -418201.5, 55283.06  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
 coord. ref. : NA 
 variables   : 3
 names       : Id, Area,          iub 
 min values  :  0,    0, 69946.845771 
 max values  :  0,    0, 69946.845771
```

EDIT** This is the error message I get when I do:

```
map(LVB.Waterbodies, add=TRUE, col=1)

Error in `[.data.frame`(x@data, i, j, ..., drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

The shapefile (additional picture) does not appear. I can make it appear using `plot(LVB.Waterbodies, col=1)` but this does not add it to the original plot, rather as a separate plot...as you suggest, this could be alignment?

[image: Original Plot]
[image: Shapefile to add]

Comment: What's going wrong here? You don't actually say and I don't see any error messages... I'm guessing its an alignment error because of `image.plot` reserving some space for the legend and anything overlaid thinks it has a full plot area and so doesn't line up... But a picture of it *not* working would be as useful as one of what you want.

Comment: @Spacedman - Thanks for the reply. I have edited my question to hopefully be clearer as to what my issue is. Any help appreciated